# Criando arquivo Makefile

Tags: c, c++, makefile, make

Estou precisando escrever um arquivo Makefile, consegui configurar algo pesquisando, mas tentei aprimorar mais para o que necessito, e não estou conseguindo. O que estou tentando fazer:

1 - Verificar todos os arquivos .c ou .cpp se possuem seus equivalentes .o

2 - Não possuindo o .o, criaria então a partir do nome do arquivo .c ou .cpp, antes verificando seus arquivos headers .h ou .hpp

3 - Queria fazer essa verificação não apenas em um diretório, mas em vários, pois meu projeto está divido em pastas, todos os arquivos em apenas uma pasta ficaria bastante desorganizado, ou seja, ele fazer os passos 1 e 2 no diretório atual e nos subdiretórios, nesses subdiretórios verificar se existe diretório..., resumindo no diretório e subdiretórios inteiro do projeto.

O que consegui até agora, porém estou recebendo este erro ao dar make:

***"Makefile:22: *** missing separator.  Pare."***(Up 2: Erro devido "$(COMPILADOR) -o $@ $^" está espaços em branco em vez de TAB, o arquivo Makefile, reconhece apenas TAB)

```
#Compilador
COMPILADOR=g++
#Fontes .c
FONTES=$(wildcard *.c|*.cpp) 
#Headers .h
HEADERS=$(wildcard *.h|*.hpp)

.PHONY: all

all: compilar

#Verifica se os fontes .c possuem seus equivalentes arquivo-objetos .o
#Possuindo, compila e cria o arquivo executavel
compilar: $(FONTES:.c|.cpp=.o)
    $(COMPILADOR) -o $@ $^

#Verifica se os arquivos .c e .cpp, ainda não entendi muito bem aqui
%.o: %.c|%.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(COMPILADOR) -c $< -o $@
```

Tutorial em que me baseei:

https://aulasdec.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/utilitarios-make-makefiles-e-sua-importancia/

> **Up 1:**

Ainda estou tentando; consegui pegar os arquivos em suas pastas, mas não estou conseguindo verificar os arquivos-objetos da pasta OBJ, pois mesmo sem arquivo .o algum na pasta, está compilando e não indo para o código de linkagem como deveria("Deveria", claro, se eu tivesse escrito o código certo).

```
#Compilador
COMPILADOR=g++
#Diretorio dos arquivos de programa
PROGRAM=./program
#Diretorio dos arquivos binarios
BIN=./bin
#Diretorio dos arquivos .h e .hpp
INCLUDE=./include
#Diretorio dos arquivos-objetos
OBJ=./obj
#Diretorio dos arquivos .c e .cpp
SRC=./src
#Diretorio dos arquivos de bibliotecas
LIB=./lib

#Para otimizar e mostrar mais avisos
FLAGS= -O3 -Wall
#Para encontrar as bibliotecas utilizadas
LIBS= -lm -L $(LIB)


#Fontes .c
FONTES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRC)/*\*.c)
#Headers .h
HEADERS=$(wildcard $(INCLUDE)/*.hpp) $(wildcard $(INCLUDE)/*.h)


.PHONY: all

all: linkar
#Verifica se os fontes .c possuem seus equivalentes arquivo-objetos .o
#Possuindo, compila e cria o arquivo executavel
#Porém não está verificando, acredito que meu erro é aqui: 
#"%.%=$(OBJ)/.o"
#Mas não consigo imaginar outra forma de fazer isso
linkar: $(FONTES:%.%=$(OBJ)/.o)
    OBJETOS=$(wildcard $(OBJ)/*.o)
    $(COMPILADOR) $(FLAGS) $(PROGRAM)/programPrincipal.cpp $(OBJETOS) -I $(INCLUDE) -o $(BIN)/arquivoExecutavel

#Aqui compila e gera os .o
%.o: $(SRC)/%.c $(HEADERS) 
    $(COMPILADOR) $(FLAGS) -c $< -I $(INCLUDE) -o $(OBJ)/$@
```

E uma dúvida(Up 2: Resolvida):

1 - É preciso colocar "-I $(INCLUDE)" quando compilo e na linkagem, ou somente quando compila os arquivos-objetos?

*Resposta = É preciso somente no pré-processamento, onde é substituído os #include pelo código do arquivo a que se refere. Então é necessário quando digo "compile" utilizando "g++ -c", ele está na verdade já fazendo o pré-processamento e compilando cada arquivo individualmente, então é necessário, como também na linkagem, pois estou chamando o arquivo .cpp com a função "int main" e se ele tiver organizado em arquivos separados, terá seu arquivo .hpp, ou seja, é necessário o "-I $(INCLUDE)" nas duas situações em que uso o g++.*

> **Up 2**:

Consegui resolver, é só mudar "%.%=$(OBJ)/.o", e mais abaixo no código onde entra novamente nessa questão que necessita do "or":

```
$(subst .c,.o,$(subst .cpp,.o,$(FONTES)))
```

Contudo, não façam isso, não é recomendado compilar código .c em compiladores c++, pode ocorrer erros, é claro se o código for muito simples, ele compila tranquilamente, mas é melhor evitar. Se realmente for preciso compilar nas duas linguagens, crie um alvo para cada uma no makefile com seu devido compilador. O que decidi fazer, foi compilar no makefile apenas o c++, quanto aos códigos em c, preferi criar bibliotecas e referi-las na linkagem.

Link com a resposta a minha dúvida quanto ao "or" no makefile que me ajudou:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743704/how-to-write-or-inside-dependencies-in-makefile/

Série de videos sobre arquivo Makefile que também me ajudou:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UX9XDkR01E

Deixarei o código aqui para caso alguém esteja com dúvidas na criação do arquivo makefile:(Up 3: Código abaixo não funcional, apenas deixei aqui para aprendizado do erro que ocorreu. O código funcionando está logo abaixo do Up 3)

```
########################################
###Script by PerguGames
###GitHub:https://github.com/PerduGames
########################################
#Arquivo Makefile 
#Arquivo para compilar executavel em c++, 
#buscando as dependencias em suas respectivas pastas
#O que acontece quando digito "make"?
#Busca dentro do diretorio atribuido na variavel "SRC" todos os arquivos .cpp
#Muda o sufixo e prefixo de todos os arquivos: "src/*.cpp" para "obj/*.o"
#Compila os arquivos .cpp e cria os arquivos .o no diretorio atribuido na variavel "OBJ"
#Linka e cria o executavel com o nome que você colocou em "coloqueAquiOnomeDoSeuExecutavel",
#buscando primeiro o arquivo principal .cpp no diretorio atribuido na variavel "PROGRAM"
#e buscando as devidas dependecias, bibliotecas e arquivos-objetos que foram criados
#O que acontece quando digito "make run"?
#Executa o programa "coloqueAquiOnomeDoSeuExecutavel",
#O que acontece quando digito "make cleanObjetos"?
#Exclui todos os arquivos .o no diretorio atribuido na variavel "OBJ"
#O que acontece quando digito "make clean"?
#Exclui todos os arquivos no diretorio atribuido na variavel "BIN" que seria seu
#executavel que deu o nome em "coloqueAquiOnomeDoSeuExecutavel"
#O que acontece quando digito "make tar"?
#Empacota todo o diretorio atual onde esta o arquivo makefile com o
#nome que voce substituir em "nomeDeSeuProjeto"
#Notas:
#Lembrem-se ao nomear o executavel em "coloqueAquiOnomeDoSeuExecutavel",
#precisa existir um arquivo .cpp com o mesmo nome no diretorio atribuido 
#na variavel "PROGRAM", para sastisfazer a dependencia do alvo,
#esse arquivo, seria seu arquivo com a funcao "int main()". 

#Compilador
COMPILADOR=g++
#Diretorio dos arquivos de programa
PROGRAM=./program
#Diretorio dos arquivos binarios
BIN=./bin
#Diretorio dos arquivos .h e .hpp
INCLUDE=./include
#Diretorio dos arquivos-objetos
OBJ=./obj
#Diretorio dos arquivos .c e .cpp
SRC=./src
#Diretorio dos arquivos de bibliotecas
LIB=./lib

#Para otimizar e mostrar mais avisos
FLAGS= -O3 -Wall
#Para encontrar as bibliotecas utilizadas(em "-lm", apenas um exemplo, caso seu compilador nao faca isso por voce)
LIBS= -lm -L $(LIB)

#Pega todos arquivos .cpp e muda os nomes para .o
#Fontes .cpp
FONTES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
#Retirar prefixo e sufixo
OBJLIMPAR=$(notdir $(basename $(FONTES)))
#Adicionar novo prefixo e sufixo
OBJETOS=$(addprefix $(OBJ)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(OBJLIMPAR)))

.PHONY: all cleanObjetos clean tar

all: compilar executaveis

#Arquivos .o do projeto
compilar: $(OBJETOS)

#Executaveis do projeto
executaveis: $(BIN)/coloqueAquiOnomeDoSeuExecutavel
    echo $(OBJETOS)

#Compilar e criar os arquivos-objetos
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(INCLUDE)/%.hpp
    $(COMPILADOR) $(FLAGS) -c $< -I $(INCLUDE) -o $@

#Linkar e criar o executavel
$(BIN)/%: $(PROGRAM)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILADOR) $(FLAGS) $< $(OBJETOS) -I $(INCLUDE) $(LIBS) -o $@

#Executar programa
run:
    $(BIN)/coloqueAquiOnomeDoSeuExecutavel

#Limpar arquivos .o
cleanObjetos:
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o

#Limpar executaveis
clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)/%

#Empacotar projeto
tar:
    tar cvjf nomeDeSeuProjeto.tar.bz2 pwd
```

Tenho apenas duas dúvidas ainda:

1 - O código ficou comentado após "/(asterisco)" no código postado, não consegui escapa-lo com "\", existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

2 - É certo fazer isso: "g++ arquivoPrincipal.cpp arquivo1.o arquivo2.o -I include/ -o arquivoExecutavel", posso compilar meu arquivo principal onde está a função "int main()" e ao mesmo tempo linkar os arquivos-objetos?

*Resposta = Não é certo, receberá um erro por não ter compilado o arquivoPrincipal.cpp, talvez não se seus arquivos estiverem sem conteúdo(como ocorreu comigo em meu diretório de teste), o certo é compilar separadamente antes o arquivo .cpp, e depois linkar todos os arquivos-objetos e bibliotecas, para assim criar o executável. Lembre-se que ao fazer dessa maneira, não será mais necessário o "-I $(INCLUDE)" na parte da linkagem, já que todos os arquivos já foram pré-processados e compilados. Segue o código funcionando no Up 3 abaixo.*

> **Up 3:**

Questão resolvida, código funcionando respondido abaixo.

Comment: 2- o ideal seria deixar a compilação de arquivos objetos individualmente. Isso facilita a própria manutenção do Makefile.

Comment: Mas dessa forma funciona, certo?, pois não recebo erro algum, e parece está tudo indo corretamente. Mas vou criar outro alvo então para a compilação do conteúdo da pasta "PROGRAM" e apenas linko no próximo alvo.

Comment: por isso que falei ideal; não entrei no mérito do certo ou errado. Na verdade, o certo em Makefile é ter alvos e comandos que transformam dependências em alvos. O como isso é feito pode ser mais fácil de dar manutenção ou não, mas estará certo

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta, irei ajeitar aqui, também creio que fique mais organizado compilar antes tudo, assim também dispensa o "-I $(INCLUDE)", já que todos os arquivos já foram pré-processados e compilados.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não seria ideal, seria o certo compilar tudo antes mesmo, pois senão ele acusa que não existe o arquivoPrincipal.o, porque não compilou o arquivoPrincipal.cpp.

Comment: não entendi seu update. Você encontrou a resposta? Se sim, é melhor você colocar como resposta, pois assim outra pessoa poderia tirar eventual dúvida caso tenha o mesmo problema

Comment: Encontrei, o Up 3 está funcionando perfeitamente, minha ultima edição foi para adicionar um link de referência de onde havia estudado sobre Makefile para chegar a resolução da questão, tinha me esquecido dele.

Comment: ótimo, então essa parte do up3 toda eu acho que deveria virar uma resposta.

Comment: Acho que ficaria estranho colocá-la como resposta, o mais certo seria colocar a questão como wiki, ela segue passos de aprendizado, mas não estou vendo a opção para isso.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Eu mesmo estou pensando em fazer isso sobre mime type no Android :-)

Comment: Pronto, coloquei como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link do código no GitHub:

https://github.com/PerduGames/Makefile

```
########################################
###Script by PerguGames
###GitHub:https://github.com/PerduGames
########################################
#Arquivo Makefile 
#Arquivo para compilar executavel em c++, 
#buscando as dependencias em suas respectivas pastas
#O que acontece quando digito "make"?
#Busca dentro do diretorio atribuido na variavel "SRC" todos os arquivos .cpp
#Muda o sufixo e prefixo de todos os arquivos: "src/*.cpp" para "obj/*.o"
#Compila os arquivos .cpp e cria os arquivos .o no diretorio atribuido na variavel "OBJ"
#Linka e cria o executavel com o nome que você colocou na variavel "NOME_EXECUTAVEL",
#buscando as bibliotecas e os arquivos-objetos que foram criados
#O que acontece quando digito "make run"?
#Executa o programa "NOME_EXECUTAVEL",
#O que acontece quando digito "make cleanObjetos"?
#Exclui todos os arquivos .o no diretorio atribuido na variavel "OBJ"
#O que acontece quando digito "make clean"?
#Exclui todos os arquivos no diretorio atribuido na variavel "BIN" que seria seu
#executavel que deu o nome em "NOME_EXECUTAVEL"
#O que acontece quando digito "make tar"?
#Empacota todo o diretorio atual onde esta o arquivo makefile com o
#nome que voce colocou na variavel "NOME_EXECUTAVEL"

#Compilador
COMPILADOR=g++
#Nome do seu executavel
NOME_EXECUTAVEL=nomeDoSeuExecutavel
#Diretorio dos arquivos binarios
BIN=./bin
#Diretorio dos arquivos .h e .hpp
INCLUDE=./include
#Diretorio dos arquivos-objetos
OBJ=./obj
#Diretorio dos arquivos .c e .cpp
SRC=./src
#Diretorio dos arquivos de bibliotecas
LIB=./lib

#Para otimizar e mostrar mais avisos
FLAGS= -O3 -Wall
#Para encontrar as bibliotecas utilizadas(em "-lm", apenas um exemplo, caso seu compilador nao faca isso por voce)
LIBS= -lm -L $(LIB)

#Pega todos arquivos .cpp e muda os nomes para .o
#Fontes .cpp
FONTES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
#Retirar prefixo e sufixo
OBJLIMPAR=$(notdir $(basename $(FONTES)))
#Adicionar novo prefixo e sufixo
OBJETOS=$(addprefix $(OBJ)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(OBJLIMPAR)))

.PHONY: all cleanObjetos clean tar

all: compilar $(NOME_EXECUTAVEL)

#Arquivos .o do projeto
compilar: $(OBJETOS)

#Compilar e criar os arquivos-objetos
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(INCLUDE)/%.hpp
    $(COMPILADOR) $(FLAGS) -c $< -I $(INCLUDE) -o $@

#Linkar e criar o executavel
$(NOME_EXECUTAVEL): $(OBJETOS)
    $(COMPILADOR) $(FLAGS) $(OBJETOS) $(LIBS) -o $(BIN)/$@

#Executar programa
run:
    $(BIN)/$(NOME_EXECUTAVEL)

#Limpar arquivos .o
cleanObjetos:
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o

#Limpar executavel
clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)/$(NOME_EXECUTAVEL)

#Empacotar projeto
tar:
    tar cvjf $(NOME_EXECUTAVEL).tar.bz2 pwd
```