# Makefile compilar todos os arquivos .c sem especificá-los

Tags: c, makefile

Estou tentando criar um Makefile que faça com que todos os arquivos `.c` sejam compilados sem que eu precise adicionar, linha por linha no Makefile, os arquivos.
Tentei acompanhar o [Criando arquivo Makefile](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215261/criando-arquivo-makefile), mas achei muito confuso. Meu interesse é o mesmo:

1 - Verificar se todos os arquivos `.c` possuem seus equivalentes `.o`;

2 - Não possuindo o `.o`, criá-lo a partir do nome do arquivo `.c`, antes verificando seus arquivos headers `.h`.

Meu Makefile atual:

```
BIN     = ./bin
OBJ     = ./obj
INCLUDE = ./include
SRC     = ./src

all:
    gcc -c "$(SRC)/Distancias.c" -o "$(OBJ)/Distancias.o"
    gcc -c "$(SRC)/ManipulaVetores.c" -o "$(OBJ)/ManipulaVetores.o"
    gcc -c "$(SRC)/Classificador.c" -o "$(OBJ)/Classificador.o"
    gcc -c "$(SRC)/ManipulaArquivos.c" -o "$(OBJ)/ManipulaArquivos.o"
    gcc -c testes.c -o "$(OBJ)/main.o"
    gcc -o $(BIN)/main.exe $(OBJ)/*.o -lm

run:
    $(BIN)/main.exe

clean:
    del /F /Q "$(OBJ)" ".o"
    del /F /Q "$(BIN)" ".exe"
```

Gostaria de fazer algo como `$(SRC)/*.c`, mas sei que não é tão simples pois dessa forma não é possível nomear os `.o`.

Quanto ao `clean`, já procurei por todo tipo de comando e não achei uma forma de fazê-lo funcionar em diferentes plataformas. Como estou no Windows, estou usando o `del`.

Answer (score 0):

[Referência](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/)

Teste.

```
zv@localhost test-make]$ ll
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 zv zv  70 nov  3 10:19 func1.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 zv zv  70 nov  3 10:20 func2.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 zv zv 277 nov  3 10:15 main.c
-rw-rw-r--. 1 zv zv  40 nov  3 10:24 Makefile

[zv@localhost test-make]$ cat Makefile 
test: $(wildcard *.c)
      $(CC) -o $@ $^

[zv@localhost test-make]$ make
cc -o test func1.c main.c func2.c

[zv@localhost test-make]$ ./test 
*
* calling func1
* in func1
* called func1
*
* calling func2
* in func2
* called func2
*
[zv@localhost test-make]$
```